# Code don't work on remix

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract CryptoAPI {

  // Define the token contract that the API will use
  Token token;

  // Define the endpoint for checking the balance of a wallet
  function balanceOf(address _wallet) public view returns (uint256) {
    return token.balanceOf(_wallet);
  }

  // Define the endpoint for sending tokens
  function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public {
    require(token.transfer(_to, _value), "Transfer failed");
  }
}
```

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract CryptoAPI {

    // Define the token contract that the API will use
    Token token;

    // Define the maximum credit limit for the wallet
    uint256 public creditLimit;

    // Define the endpoint for checking the balance of a wallet
    function balanceOf(address _wallet) public view returns (uint256) {
        // Check if the wallet has reached the credit limit
        if (token.balanceOf(_wallet) >= creditLimit) {
            // Return zero if the credit limit has been reached
            return 0;
        } else {
            // Return the balance of the wallet if the credit limit has not been reached
            return token.balanceOf(_wallet);
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: This is unreadable, you do not show the error message and do not explain what you are doing. Nobody will help you with these if you do not change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me too tried code.

You correct, code don't work on remix.

Jokes on the side, you need to define the Token contract that you are using without explaining to the compiler what it is.

So above your contract, declare another contract that has the token logic (i.e. the functions like .transfer, .balanceOf, ...)